# How to turn off hardware decoding option of VLC Media Player for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, vlc

I'm making a video stream app using VLC player.

I installed `mobileVLCKit-unstable` and successfully streamed video but it stops within 1 minute.

I found out that the VLC library's 'hardware decoding' option is 'on'. But I can't find how to do it.

This is what I tried:

```
myplayer = VLCMediaPlayer
myplayer.media.addOptions(["network-caching":1000]) // this is hint
myplayer.media.addOptions(["hardware-decoding":false]) // i tried, but not worked
myplayer.media.addOptions(["avcodec":false]) // i tried, but not worked
```

I'm using Swift 4, Xcode 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn’t use the unstable pod of MobileVLCKit anymore. This is no longer needed and will give you a very old and unstable version of the library as we no longer update this pod. Just use the normal MobileVLCKit pod and try again.

Disabling hardware decoding will NOT solve your problem. Please post a debug log of the stable library so we can take a more detailed look.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll consider about normal MobileVLCKit.
I want how to disable hardware decoding somehow.. Because In vlc application, disabling hardware decoding perfectly worked. so I'm looking for same way of pod.

Comment: Take a look at the VLC-iOS app source code. This option is documented there, but note that we consider it private API and can in theory break if you update VLC in the future.

Comment: Thanks for comment

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem. 
I added an option

```
let option : [String] = ["--codec=avcodec"]
let player : VLCMediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer(options : options)
```

Then I confirmed the playing time of over 30 minutes.